# How can I transform a data file(xml, json, yaml) to an executable C file?

Tags: json, xml, parsing, raspberry-pi, yaml

I have an XML(JSON, YAML) file of test cases and I want to transform those test cases into actions/instructions.

example of those test cases:

```
<steps>
    <step id="et0">
        <Action>Press Button 1</Action>
        <Excpected_Result>LED 1 is ON</Excpected_Result>
        <Description>LED 1 is turned ON when the Button 1 is 
pressed</Description>
   </step>
   <step id="et1">
        <Action>Press Button 2</Action>
        <Excpected_Result>Relay 2 becomes active for two 
seconds</Excpected_Result>
        <Description>Relay 2 becomes active for two seconds when Button 2 
is pressed</Description>
    </step>
</steps>
```

P.S: I am working with raspberry pi 3

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please read page https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and paste here your xml code except the image.

Comment: There are lots of test frameworks that allow you to write test cases in XML or some other format, and autogenerate code for you. Or you implement it yourself. In any case, a precondition is that `Action` and `Expected_Result` are machine readable (i.e. the converter needs to understand their meaning), which is not really the case here. You have to show the desired output; without knowing what you want to produce, we can't really help you.

Comment: How can I let the  Actions and Expected_Result readable? For example the Buttons would be outputs of the raspberry GPIO pins.

Comment: Wouldn't a button rather be an input? Are you looking for a software mocking physical I/O? It is increasingly unclear what you want to do, you should at least describe what the generated code should do so others can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Generally speaking the project I am working on is a Raspberry pi3 and two "Stations", transmission and reception. In the 'transmission station' we have two buttons (inputs) and in the 'Reception station' we have a relay and a LED. The main idea is to test two things; the first is once I press the button 1 the LED turn ON and once I press button 2 the relay becomes active. In fact there is more than this two things to test,in order to keep it simple I suggested this two button tests.

Comment: The final code I want to generate would be a script that imports the xml file and would test all the steps and return either succeed or failed for each step.